# Which version of linux kernel is Android O (8.0) using?

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I tried to find something on [AOSP](https://source.android.com/) but there was only about 7.X version. Will they use 4.9.X or newer? The android setting shows that the kernel version of my Android O DP3 is 3.10.73, but as far as I know it is not the same with linux kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the device manufacturer. So if you see 3.10.73, it means you're really having that version. Normally when Android is updated for a device, kernel is not upgraded to a major version, so you can only expect newer kernels when a new device comes out. Most likely it will be 4.4 because looks like work on android-specific 4.9 kernel has only recently begun and it takes several months for OEMs and SoC vendors to port drivers and get rid of bugs.

Comment: thank you. My device is Nexus 6P, not that old. It is surprising that they are using such an old kernel on last years flagship phone.